# Can't retrieve AppSettings in asp.net mvc 6 beta 8

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a new ASP.Net MV5 project (currently beta8) for learning purpose.

I'm stuck with simple case of getting app settings.

I've added some configuration in the appsettings.json file:

```
{
  "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet5-someproject-e84e86e2-0fec-4132-9a91-2f6c4b4c61a3;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    }
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "CloudStorageContainerReference": "someproject",
    "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

I've also created a strongly typed class:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public string CloudStorageContainerReference { get; set; }
    public string StorageConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

And updated my startup file:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add Entity Framework services to the services container.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        // Add Identity services to the services container.
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add settings
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Register application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }
```

At this point, if I break the code, I can see that `Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Value` is null.

Further, I want to inject these settings in my controllers:

```
public class TransfertController : Controller
{
    private IOptions<AppSettings> AppSettings;

    public TransfertController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
    {
        if (AppSettings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appSettings));

        AppSettings = appSettings;
    }

}
```

But it throw a `NullReferenceException` as my `appSettings` parameter is null.

What is missing?

**[Edit]**: as a side note, this line:

```
Configuration["AppSettings:CloudStorageContainerReference"]
```

Returns actually the correct single value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it was just a typo in your original code:

```
public TransfertController(IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
{
    if (AppSettings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));

    AppSettings = appSettings;
}
```

In your guard, you are checking the same property `AppSettings` that you are assigning, before assigning it. You want the guard to check the method input parameter, not your property as in `if (appSettings == null) throw new ...` (notice the lower case **appSettings**)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand why, but I solved the issue by renaming my class member "AppSettings" to "Settings", and unwrapping the IOptions:

```
public class TransfertController : Controller
{
    private readonly AppSettings Settings;

    public TransfertController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
    {
        if (settings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(settings));

        Settings = settings.Value;
    }
}
```

is now working...